# how to add text to an item Qt

Tags: c++, qt

My problem is that i have created a class Item that paints polygones and what i want to do is to add some text to these item...Like Class in UML we got the class name and some attributs...to be more clear i want to create a simple tool form uml class with Qt and i created a class which can paint the entity but its just a simple polygone with 2 areas one for the class name and the other for the attributs,my question is how can i add the text to the polygone with the possibility to change it...please i really need some help here and thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do that

1. Use `QPainter::drawText()` functions, and draw text directly.
2. Use `QPainterPath::addText()` and then `QPaitner::fillPath()` or `QPainter::drawPath()`, this method is more difficult because the coordinates given are the base line bottom left corner.
3. If you are drawing on a `QGraphicsScene` then a text item can be added.

Comment: thanks for your help , i already used a text item but how can i attach it to the polygon cause i created a itempolygon class and a textitem class but i don't know how to add it to my diagram class and attach it to my polygon

Comment: @QossaiLabyad You need to compute where the text would go and `setPos()` I think, I don't remember the method's name, but it's something like that, Qt's documentation is really good, so you can just google for the right method. Also, قصي you can mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: okay thanks for your help, i think it s gonna help me alot to read the documentation :p i forgot about it